# How to get the object or item of a Single with rxJava?

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, rx-java2

I would like to know how to obtain the value contained in a Single and contain it in a variable? (In the example that I am going to add, capturing it is a String, but I would like its proposals to be indifferent to the type since it could be an object created by oneself or another type whatever), mention that in this case it would no longer accept a blockingGet() which for concepts I would like to keep the detail async.

In the current context it is shown that the map still gets a Single, but my goal is still to get just String, its support with the fundamentals to be able to understand this detail that has emerged when researching and practicing rxJava.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYDp6.png)

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this which is asynchronous:

```
String variableString="";
    a.subscribe( result -> {
          variableString = result.toString();
        });
    System.out.println(convertToSentence(variableString));
```